# How communication is enabled in multiple different network using different routing protocols

Tags: network

I do have challenge in ensure communication between my organization and different stack holder organization connectivity as in my network we are using static route and vendors are using OSPF routing protocol we had planned to implement point -point dedicated lease line my doubt is how I need to enable communication between two networks using different routing protocol

Comment: I certainly hope you have a firewall established between you and the vendor. Remember that the breach that cost Target many millions of dollars was caused when a vendor was was hacked. You do not control the vendor network, nor do you vet its employees or vendors. You cannot simply trust another company.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The optimized way to accomplished this task is by `redistribution of route`   please check restribution of route concept . We have fesabilty to export and import route in different routing protocols   for example if ospf and static routing to communication redistribution has to be configured in border switch

Assuming you are having cisco layer3 switch connecting two different network in his layer3 switch  redistribution of routes can be configured between static and OSPF route ensure advertising OSFP route into static route and static route in ospf

`Router1(config)#router ospf 78 Router1(config-router)#redistribute static      Router1(config-router)#exit Router1(config)#end`

Likewise we can redistribute route from and to vice versa between different routing protocols

Comment: I need to check with vendor...

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have multiple paths to the other organization, you don't need to run a routing protocol with them.  You can use a static route to route traffic over the point to point link, and the other organization can do the same.

One of the assumptions of OSPF is that all routers are trusted.  In your case, the routers of the other organization should **NOT** be trusted, so OSPF is not a good choice.  If you had to run a routing protocol, BGP is a better choice, but it doesn't seem to be necessary in your case.

Comment: But my vendor is using ospf he is not ready to use static routing

Comment: I think you're confused about what routing protocols do.  The vendor doesn't have to change their protocol - they still use OSPF.  They just need to add one static route and redistribute it.  Whatever you do, do NOT run OSPF with your vendor -- that is very insecure.

Comment: @JojijohnJoji, what your vendor does or does not do is none of your concern, and neither is what you do any of the vendor's concern. We call separate routing domains Autonomous Systems, and each does what it does on its own. The vendor could actually use static routes on its connection to you and redistribute those into its OSPF. You do not care how it does what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, BGP is an appropriate routing protocol for inter-domain / inter-network signaling.  It has features intended for networks which are under different administrative controls.

OSPF is not appropriate for your intended use.  Don't do that.  OSPF is categorized as an **Interior Routing Protocol** specialized at distributing routing information within one network under the control of a single organization.